# pass function as a callback to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jdialog

I have this code:

```
$('.b-icon.b-icon_del').click(function(e) {
showConfirmDialog('Are you sure you want to delete this document?',deleteDocument(window.lastSelectedRowId), 'Delete document');                    
}); 

function showConfirmDialog(content, callback, pTitle, obj){
    return showDialogEx(content, callback, pTitle, obj, "Yes", "No");
}

function showDialogEx(content, callback, pTitle, obj, okButtonLabel, cancelButtonLabel){
    var str = "#_showMessageDialog";
    var showMessageDialog = $(str);
    if(showMessageDialog.length == 0){
        $('body').append('<div id="_showMessageDialog"></div>');
        showMessageDialog = $(str);
    }
    showMessageDialog.val("");
    showMessageDialog.append('<p id="_showMessageDialogContent">'.concat(content, '</p>'));

    var my_buttons = {};
    my_buttons[cancelButtonLabel] = function(){
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $(this).html("");
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
    };
    my_buttons[okButtonLabel] = function(){
        callback();
        $(this).html("");
        $(this).dialog("close");
        if(obj){
            obj.focus();
        }
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
    };

    showMessageDialog.dialog({
        modal : true,
        resizable : true,
        title : pTitle,
        minWidth : 250,
        width : 450,
        buttons : my_buttons
    });

}
```

And then I click on button with classes `.b-icon.b-icon_del` it seems like executing both `deleteDocument(window.lastSelectedRowId)` and `showConfirmDialog('Are you sure you want to delete this document?',deleteDocument(window.lastSelectedRowId), 'Delete document');`
 at the moment. I just want that callback function (which is `deleteDocument(window.lastSelectedRowId)`) invoke after user clicks "OK" button. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, wrap `deleteDocument(window.lastSelectedRowId)` in a function to prevent it from being evaluated prematurely at the call to `$('.b-icon.b-icon_del').click()`.

i.e.

```
$('.b-icon.b-icon_del').click(function(e) {
showConfirmDialog('Are you sure you want to delete this document?', function() { return deleteDocument(window.lastSelectedRowId); }                  
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wrap callback in `function() { deleteDocument(window.lastSelectedId) }` and it's working good. Easy solution. What's the difference between calling `function() { deleteDocument(window.lastSelectedRowId) }` and `function() { return deleteDocument(window.lastSelectedRowId);` ?

Comment: No different really unless you have to return something from the wrapper function. (Old habits die hard... (Wrapper function with returns are usually needed for old-style event handlers.))  I have to say James Khoury's solution is really neat (use of apply() and the argument object) and is useful in languages where such wrapping is not as easy.

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the function `deleteDocument(window.lastSelectedRowId)` when you pass it as the second argument `showConfirmDialog`.

You should just pass it, as well as the argument `window.lastSelectedRowId`, along to `showConfirmDialog` without executing it.

```
$('.b-icon.b-icon_del').click(function(e) {
showConfirmDialog('Are you sure you want to delete this document?',deleteDocument, window.lastSelectedRowId, 'Delete document');                    
}); 

function showConfirmDialog(content, callback, rowId, pTitle, obj){
    return showDialogEx(content, callback, rowId, pTitle, obj, "Yes", "No");
}

function showDialogEx(content, callback, rowId, pTitle, obj, okButtonLabel, cancelButtonLabel){
    var str = "#_showMessageDialog";
    var showMessageDialog = $(str);
    if(showMessageDialog.length == 0){
        $('body').append('<div id="_showMessageDialog"></div>');
        showMessageDialog = $(str);
    }
    showMessageDialog.val("");
    showMessageDialog.append('<p id="_showMessageDialogContent">'.concat(content, '</p>'));

    var my_buttons = {};
    my_buttons[cancelButtonLabel] = function(){
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $(this).html("");
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
    };
    my_buttons[okButtonLabel] = function(){
        callback(rowId);
        $(this).html("");
        $(this).dialog("close");
        if(obj){
            obj.focus();
        }
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
    };

    showMessageDialog.dialog({
        modal : true,
        resizable : true,
        title : pTitle,
        minWidth : 250,
        width : 450,
        buttons : my_buttons
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. It'll be better if callback function has variant list of arguments 'cause I did use this function in a lot of places in project.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.b-icon.b-icon_del').click(function(e) {
showConfirmDialog('Are you sure you want to delete this document?',deleteDocument, [window.lastSelectedRowId], 'Delete document');                    
}); 

function showConfirmDialog(content, callback, callbackArguments, pTitle, obj){
    return showDialogEx(content, callbackArguments,  pTitle, obj, "Yes", "No");
}
```

and in:

```
function showDialogEx(content, callback, callbackArguments, pTitle, obj, okButtonLabel, cancelButtonLabel)
```

the lines:

```
my_buttons[okButtonLabel] = function(){
    callback();
```

Should be:

```
my_buttons[okButtonLabel] = function(){
    callback.apply(this, callbackArguments);
```

It is important to note that callbackArguments is a list `["value']` even if it only has one value.

Comment: This is a good approach but I prefer to wrap callback function in `function() { }` and use it this way.

Comment: Its all a matter of preference. this way you aren't creating a new function every time its called. It also has the benefits of being able to specify what `this` refers to and in some situations that is quite important.